# Huawei и Google сервисы

Tags: android, google-services

Возник вопрос, что там с новыми Huawei и Google сервисами в нем?

1. Будет ли гугл карта на них?
2. Да и вообще сервисы гугл

Кто нибудь в курсе?
p.s. попутно гуглю)

Comment: Ничего гуглового нет на новых Huawei

Comment: Похоже, что это так. В гугле тоже только информация как поставить вручную... :(

Comment: На данный момент только в ручную. Сам столкнулся с этой проблемой когда купил Huawei P40 Lite. На 4PDA есть подробные инструкции как поставить сервисы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На новых Huawei девайсах нет гугло-сервисов.

Это означает, что не будут работать приложения (или часть их функционала), если требуются гугло сервисы. Например, не будут работать карты, определение местоположения, пуши, аналитика.

Чтобы всё работало есть 2 пути:

1. Искать в магазине Huawei аналог нужного приложения, в котором используются аналоги гугло сервисов от Huawei.
2. Устанавливать гугло-сервисы вручную из к-л сторонних источников. Это опасно, т.к. в неофициальных источниках могут быть вредоносные куски кода и работать оно может нестабильно.